# Magento add a CMS page into multiple store

Tags: php, magento

I have created two different stores in my site.
Imaging second store name is `Test`. i have add the `index.php` file into the `Test` store using following code;

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
Mage::run('testfolder', 'website');
```

Here `testfolder` is the folder which is include `index.php` file related to the `Test` store. I need to add another CMS page in to my new store.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this.

Comment: why are you modfiying `index.php` file in order to setup a store wise CMS Page ??? Bad Idea

Answer (score 1):

When you add CMS page you can select the store on which you want to show this page. Please check screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: yes, then how can i browse it? i need the Url. Can you please tell me that.

Comment: As you have multi store setup .. you can access in that particular store using the URL key.

Comment: you can debug by assign page to all stores .. and if page will load correctly then you have some issue in set up multi store

Comment: But when i am loading the home page of my new store, it is working fine. It  is not working only for the second page

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with my case. I had missed index.php in between the new store and the cms page name.